# NUSerDefaults data wiped out in iPod 14.4.2

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults, ios14

I am storing some data (just a plain string) NSUserDefaults. When I kill the app by double-tapping the home button and relaunch the app my data got wiped out. It was happening on iPod with 14.4.2 OS. The same thing working fine on other devices. Following is my code for saving it.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 [defaults setObject:@"myStirng" forKey:@"mydata"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Following is the code that I am using to get the data from defaults.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString* myStirng = [defaults objectForKey:@"mydata"];
NSLog(@"%@",myStirng);
```

Comment: Why don't you save and load on the `documents` folder instead of user default?

Comment: Hi ChandraSekhar. Please try to refrain from adding needy begging messages to your posts here. It doesn't encourage more responses, and may discourage them.